# Interpretation of the result of "cat /proc/bus/input/devices" and adb shell commands

Tags: android, shell, events, adb, code-injection

I'm unsure if the question about injecting events via adb is supposed to be in StackOverflow or [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), please move it if it doesn't belong here.

Anyway, my question is as follows.

I obviously have to determine the "type" of device for sending and receiving events. I can't obviously send a touch event to the keypad device.

After a lot of research I found the `sendevent` and `getevent` commands.

So, I want to send a long press to the power button of a phone.

I use this currently:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event3 1 116 0
sendevent /dev/input/event3 1 116 1
```

This works on the [**HTC Wildfire**](http://pastebin.com/wkS9vNFz)(click on the link for the input devices) because the keypad contains the power button and `116` happens to be the scan code for the power key.

I know what `/dev/input/event3/` and `116` and `0 or 1` stand for. What does the `1` in-between `/dev/input/event3/` and `116` stand for? How do I obtain it?

Moving on to the [**Nexus 4**](http://pastebin.com/Ef4VfFFj). Now, I've noticed that it has a separate powerkey and keypad handler

**[EDIT]**

Found [**this**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1875094) regarding `sendevent` and `getevent` on XDA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1` "in-between /dev/input/event3/ and 116" stands for [EV_KEY](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt) event type constant:

> - EV_KEY:
>     Used to describe state changes of keyboards, buttons, or other key-like
>     devices.

You could have found that on your own if you had run `getevent -l /dev/input/event3/` and pressed the power key.

Also to find out the power key input device name I would recommend parsing output of `getevent -pl` instead of contents of `/proc/bus/input/devices`. The device you are looking for has `KEY_POWER` listed in the events section:

```
add device X: /dev/input/eventX
  name:     "xxxxxxxxxx"
  events:
    KEY (0001): KEY_POWER
```

And the proper long power key press sequence (as in press and hold for 1 second and then release) would be:

```
sendevent /dev/input/eventX 1 116 1
sendevent /dev/input/eventX 0 0 0
sleep 1
sendevent /dev/input/eventX 1 116 0
sendevent /dev/input/eventX 0 0 0
```

Note: `getevent -pl` is not available for Gingerbread and below.

Comment: Where would I be able to retrieve the `EV_KEY` for a particular device?

Comment: EV_KEY = 1. It is a linux kernel constant. It has not changed since its inception and I doubt it would change in the future. The `KEY (0001):` line in the `getevent -pl` output is just a short way of saying `EV_KEY = 0x0001`

Comment: Thank you very much! I did figure out the `getevent` bit. I didn't know that it would make a difference while sending the actual commands. Assumed that `sendevent /dev/input/eventX 0 0 0` is `sleep 1`. My bad.