# Writing to /dev/input/mice doesn't work for simulating mouse clicks

Tags: c, linux, mouse

As far as I know, in Linux, inputs from hardware devices can be thought as writing data to files, so I think that it is quite possible to write something to `/dev/input/mice` for simulating mouse click without using `X`.

This is what I have done:

```
root@linux:~$ sudo cat /dev/input/mice >> right-click
(click the right button of your mouse, and then press ctrl+c to terminate it.)
root@linux:~$ sudo cat right-click >> /dev/input/mice
```

I did this for testing whether writing something to `/dev/input/mice` can simulate mouse click or not, but obviously it failed. Any reasons?

Comment: There is a tool for same purpose `xdotool` and here is some [uses](http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse) [sample](http://xmodulo.com/simulate-key-press-mouse-movement-linux.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Control mouse by writing to /dev/input/mice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595716/control-mouse-by-writing-to-dev-input-mice)

Answer (score 1):

The reasons that writing to a device fails is that the kernel mouse driver does not take bytes from the device file and send them back to the device file.

Suppose you had a serial mouse. Writing bytes to a serial port, would you expect to read those bytes back from the same serial port? Bytes written to a device file might be read by the device, they should not be expected to be readable back from the device file.