# how to move cursor using hand tracking in c++ opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have done hand tracking in opencv in c++. Now I want to move cursor with hand tracking. Please tell me about the functions i can use and how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library pyautogui(https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) may be helpful, but it's written in python. You can call python fuctions in C++, although it would cost you a little effort. What's more, if you want to move cursor by yourself and you are using linux system, congratulations, the mouse cursor is a device file, you can move it by write the formated data to it. The detail you can find it with google. Or you can refer this question: [Control mouse by writing to /dev/input/mice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595716/control-mouse-by-writing-to-dev-input-mice)

Comment: i am using windows 10