# Sending mouse click events to other windows in Linux without moving the mouse

Tags: c++, linux, winapi, mouseclick-event, xdotool

I have a Windows application which I want to port it to Linux. In this application, I send mouse click events to other applications. The function which does the job is like this:

```
void MainWindow::send_mouse_event(HWND hwnd, int x, int y)
{
    int coordinate = x | (y << 16);
    LRESULT res = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x00000001, coordinate);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x00000000, coordinate);
}
```

I searched for equivalent code in Linux and I found [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool). As far as I understood, using `xdotool`, you have to move the mouse to a point at first, and then click that point. But in Windows, I could send mouse click events virtually to other windows without moving the mouse. So is the story true about Linux? Is it possible to send a click event to other applications without (really) moving the mouse in Linux? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: A related question already posted in SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595716/control-mouse-by-writing-to-dev-input-mice

Comment: While you're at it, consider fixing the Windows version, too: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). The same underlying principles apply to mouse input.

Comment: @IInspectable But it's working :D anyway, thank you, I'll fix it.